# How to use RECORD or CURSOR in where conduction

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am writing a stored procedure which needs to return document id
this document id is can be any of the two fields.
APP_DOC_ID (added from app) BTCH_DOC_D(added from batch) both are different fields in same table.

I need to get those docid's based on subquery.

```
SELECT DISTINCT APP_DOC_ID FROM
(SELECT APP_DOC_ID FROM XXXXXX BC WHERE BC.XX||BC.XY||BC.XZ IN 
(SUBQUERY))
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT BTCH_DOC_ID FROM
(SELECT BTCH_DOC_ID FROM XXXXXX BC WHERE BC.XX||BC.XY||BC.XZ IN 
(SUBQUERY))
```

My SUBQUERY is little complicated so I don’t want to run that query 2 time 1 APP_DOC_ID and BTCH_DOC_ID,
Is it possible to save subquery results in RECORD or CURSOR and use it both query’s

Like

```
BEGIN
OPEN P_CURSOR FOR (Select AB.XX||AB.XY||AB.XZ from ....)
SELECT DISTINCT APP_DOC_ID FROM
    (SELECT APP_DOC_ID FROM XXXXXX BC WHERE BC.XX||BC.XY||BC.XZ IN P_CURSOR)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT BTCH_DOC_ID FROM
(SELECT BTCH_DOC_ID FROM XXXXXX BC WHERE BC.XX||BC.XY||BC.XZ IN P_CURSOR)
```

this this approach I am not running my complex subquery 2 times.

Thanks for your help and time

Comment: You've tagged this for MySQL and SQL Server which are two completely different database engines.  Then you tagged it PL/SQL which is a language that only exists in an Oracle database which is a third completely different database engine.  Which database are you really using?  My guess from your syntax is that you are using Oracle and the MySQL and SQL Server tags should be removed but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WITH` clause:

```
WITH subquery AS(
  SELECT .... your complex subquery goes here
)
SELECT DISTINCT APP_DOC_ID FROM
(SELECT APP_DOC_ID FROM XXXXXX BC WHERE BC.XX||BC.XY||BC.XZ IN 
(SELECT * FROM SUBQUERY))
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT BTCH_DOC_ID FROM
(SELECT BTCH_DOC_ID FROM XXXXXX BC WHERE BC.XX||BC.XY||BC.XZ IN 
(SELECT * FROM SUBQUERY SUBQUERY))
```

See this link for details: [subquery factoring clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702)

> The WITH query_name clause lets you assign a name to a subquery block.
>   You can then reference the subquery block multiple places in the query
>   by specifying query_name. Oracle Database optimizes the query by
>   treating the query name as either an inline view or as a temporary
>   table.